# Prolog output message understanding

Tags: prolog

This is a really quick one, I don't know the correct way to google it!

Say we have an output such it gives:

```
X = [4|_1218]
```

what generally has to be changed to get the output just to say 4?

```
member1(Head, [Head|_]):-!.   
member1(Item, [_|Tail]):-
    member1(Item, Tail).


findnotin([Head|_], RuledOut, [Head|_]):-
    not(member1(Head, RuledOut)).
```

Edit Completedish program:

```
find_not_in([], _, _).
find_not_in([Head|Candidates], RuleOut, [Head|Legal]):-
    not(member1(Head, RuleOut)),
    find_not_in(Candidates, RuleOut, Legal).

find_not_in([_|Candidates], RuleOut, Legal):-
    find_not_in(Candidates, RuleOut, Legal).
```

Comment: What is the query? Don't you mean `[4]`?

Comment: findnotin([4,2,1,6],[2,1,6], X). @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: I have updated the program a little @WillemVanOnsem I just want some guidance really

Comment: try testing with base case: `find_not_in([], _, []).`

Comment: It works perfectly, I just dont understand it, I thought were printing the last paramater? @coder

Comment: Can you explain what `find_not_in([], _, _)` means? I don't think it means what you think it means. Also, you don't need `member1/2`. Just use `memberchk/2` which Prolog already has.

Comment: You have instantiated the output list in the recursive rules by unifying the elements with elements of the first list when it not empty. When first list is empty you want to say that also the third list is empty, nothing more to add from first list. To say that you don't put an anonymous variable `_` but empty list []

Comment: Want to also say that the third list is empty? @coder but it isn't?

Comment: I know I can use memberchk/2 @lurker I'm just trying to learn prolog by writing the predicates myself

Comment: To be clear, `find_not_in([], _, _)` is saying that the result of not finding anything from your empty list in any rules is anything. The result shouldn't be anything. The result should be an empty list. So `find_not_in([], _, [])`.

Comment: So why wouldn't it be something like find_not_in([], _, List). @lurker

Comment: Because `like find_not_in([], _, List)` is same with like `find_not_in([], _, _)` but with the problem of singleton variable List, what you want is like `find_not_in([], _, List):- List = []` which is same with like `find_not_in([], _, []).`.

Comment: Put simply, ` find_not_in([], _, List).` is wrong because it says the same wrong thing: *the result of not finding anything from your empty list in any rules is any list.* It just so happens that, in this case, you named *any list* as `List` instead of anonymously with `_`. It's still *any* list rather than the correct instance, which would be specifically the empty list `[]`.